# Matrix of Matrices in Python

Tags: programming-languages, matrices

I want to create a matrix where each entry itself is a random matrix. 
What would be a good way to represent this?

It is not necessary but some hints on how to implement your proposed solution in Python would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is just a higher dimensional array.

Let's say you want a 5x5 array where each element is a 2x2 array with random number. You can easily represent that as a 5x5x2x2 array.

If you are happy about using numpy

```
A = numpy.random.rand(5,5,2,2)
```

Will create a 5x5x2x2 array.

You can use the first two indexes to access your 2D random arrays.

```
print A[1,1]
```

Results in:

```
[[ 0.68527006  0.37304491]
 [ 0.23281899  0.46951261]]
```